# AWS SES Guzzle Error when sending email

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk

I have set up AWS Ses service using PHP SDK:

```
$this->client = SesClient::factory([
    'key' => $params['key'],
    'secretKey' => $params['secret_key'],
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'base_url' => 'https://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
]);

$this->client->sendEmail($this->params());

public function params() {
    array(
        'Source' => 'verified@gmail.com',
        'Destination' => array(
            'ToAddresses' => array('receiver@yahoo.com')
        ),
        'Message' => array(
            'Subject' => array(
                'Data' => 'SES Testing',
                'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
            ),
            // Body is required
            'Body' => array(
                'Text' => array(
                    'Data' => 'My plain text email',
                    'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
                ),
                'Html' => array(
                    'Data' => '<b>My HTML Email</b>',
                    'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'ReplyToAddresses' => array( 'replyTo@email.com' ),
        'ReturnPath' => 'bounce@email.com'
    );
}
```

After trying to send email, I receive this error message:

```
exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message 
'[curl] 23: Failed writing body (0 != 86) [url] https://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\protected\lib\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php:338
```

Anyone know how to fix that error?

cUrl has support for SMTP, but `smtp://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` throws error `[curl] 1: Protocol smtp not supported or disabled in libcurl [url] smtp://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/`
[image: cUrl]

Comment: That is a transport exception. AWS Ses Service should have shielded that one, report this as a bug upstream.

Comment: @hakre Do you know how to get around this exception?

Comment: You can't. It's in there. It's thrown when applicable. You can catch it but instead you should report this problem upstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `https://email.{$region}.amazonaws.com` as `base_url`
   *At this stage, i get error: 'User 'arn:aws:iam::######:user/ebpush' is not authorized to perform 'ses:SendEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:447362101282:identity/verified@gmail.com'*
2. Add *IAM* > *Groups* > *Create group* > *AmazonSESFullAccess*
3. Go to *IAM* > *Policies* > *AmazonSESFullAccess* > *Attach* > *ebPush*

**OR**

Use PHPMailer to connect via `email-smtp.{region}.amazonaws.com` where Username is your SES Access Key and password is your SES Secret Key

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a valid endpoint.

`email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` is the SMTP endpoint, not HTTPS.  The HTTPS endpoint is `email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ses_region

Comment: When I replace `base_url` with `smtp://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` it says `Protocol smtp not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Comment: When using just `email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`: `<url> malformed`

Comment: What? No... use `https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.  You don't want SMTP for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set the base_url/endpoint explicitly in AWS SDK for PHP. Setting the region will ensure the proper endpoint is used.